# Replacing text using sed

Tags: bash, sed

What am I doing wrong?

```
sed -i 's/** [out :: apple.mango@machine-6.mysite.com]/machine-6/g' file1.csv
Error -: sed: -e expression #1, char 58: Invalid range end
```

I basically want to replace apple.mango@machine-6.mysite.com with just machine-6 through bash?

Additionally, I want to do this for all machines (7 of them), so will I have to write this line individually for each, or can I use the same replace line for all of them?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets are special characters. When you mean them literally, you need to escape them, as well as dots:

```
\[out :: apple\.mango@machine-6\.mysite\.com\]
```

Also, if you mean the asterisks literally, it's better to escape them, as well.

And yes, you can write a loop to run through 7 machine numbers using `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 7); do
    sed -i "s/\*\* \[out :: apple\.mango@machine-$i\.mysite\.com]/machine-$i/g" file1.csv
done
```

Note the double quotes I used here, as single quotes prevernt variable expansion.

Comment: Thanks....Any help with the second part? Do I write it individually for each machine or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Can I ask you something not related to this question, here? I have a bunch of garbage text in a file before suppose the word 'machine'. Why will this not work -: sed '/^(*)machine/d' file1.csv?

Comment: @PratikBothra For a number of reasons. 1) `*` doesn't work by itself, it's only a quantifier that can follow a pattern. E.g. `.` is a pattern matching any char. So `.*` will mean any text, but `*` is not a pattern. 2) `sed` matches brackets `()` literally by default. To use them for grouping, you escape them. But if you provide `-r` option to `sed`, it will work the opposite way (plain `()` for grouping). 3) `sed` is line-based, so `^.*machine` will match a line that has `machine`, but won't match all previous lines.  But you can try `sed '0,/machine/d'` file1.csv

Comment: I was doing the 1st correctly until a few moments ago, the second was frustration, the 3rd I'd no idea about. How is sed '0,/machine/d' supposed to work? The text before regex is line separated

Comment: @PratikBothra If I understand you correctly and you want to delete all lines up to the one with `machine`, you need an address range (not sure why I used `0`, line numbers obviously start with `1`). Take a look [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29) for further explanation